# multiple config file in c#

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a solution containing 1 console application and 2 libraries.

In the libraries I have two different app.configs for an example my data.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="OutputFileFolder" value="c:\\log" />
    <add key="OutputIndexFile" value="c:\\log\index.xml" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And in this library class I have in the constructor

```
_indexPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OutputIndexFile"];
```

But how should I load the `Data.config` file from my main console application (this should be the main config file)?

Answer (score 4):

Config files in your dll projects are not relevant at runtime. The config file (if any) in your console application project is the one that will get used.

If you want to use a configuration file in two separate projects, you can add it [as a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28VS.80%29.aspx) to your second project, or you could use a [post-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) to copy it over. However both of these seem a little hacky.

Answer (score 2):

Libraries don't really have associated configuration files as such - they operate under an executable (a console application, in your case).

You should put *all* the configuration in the `app.config` file of the application for the code in the libraries to have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can load multiple config files by have multiple [`Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) instances from multiple calls to [`ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx) (add your config file to the file map, the global file will be added automatically and specify a [`ConfigurationUserLevel.None`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationuserlevel.aspx).

Something like:

```
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap {
                    ExeConfigFilename = Path of dll's config file
             };

var cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var result = cfg.AppSettings["OutputIndexFile"];
```