# Storing settings in configFile

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, settings, config

Try to save all data in to config file, and then read it and apply to my program during running - as user preference.
Whats done: create new config file (using Add new element-> add congif file). In this file put simple code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSetting>
        <add Key="Volume" value="100" />
    </appSetting>
</configuration>
```

After it create method

```
public int GetVolumeFromConfigFile()
    {
        return  Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Volume"));
    }
```

and in main programm call it like

```
Value = (MyClass.GetVolumeFromConfigFile());
```

But it's not work. (During debaggin it's return nothing)

Think it can be few reason:

1. I need to add (I don't now in what way) what config file to use, because i have few files *.config - one as default (App.exe.config, and another - that i created)
2. I use incorrect method to get value from config file

Also I read about some another way to store app settings, like store it in *.settings file
What I'm doing wrong and what method prefered?

Additional information - use net 4.0

**EDIT**

Remove my config file, and add to existed few lines (in  strong>)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="PlayDemo.SettingsPlayIt" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
       </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <PlayDemo.SettingsPlayIt>
            <setting name="Volume" serializeAs="String">
                <value>10</value>
            </setting>
        </PlayDemo.SettingsPlayIt>
    </userSettings>
```

Here I add my key

```
    <appSetting>
        <add key="Volume" value="100" />
    </appSetting>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
      <appSettings>
         <add key="Volume" value="100" />
      </appSettings>
   </configuration>
```

and

```
return  Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Volume"]);
```

the appSettings are key value pairs, so you can access it like you would a value in a Dictionary

Comment: and how about using of few config file - are I must to "say" programm in what file my app must to search required key? or it search in all config files?

Comment: i'd look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761852/multiple-config-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: try  it nothing change

Comment: look at that post - so if i want to use few config files ineed to use some dll files? i'm just a begginer, so if you have some tutorial link or sample of code - it's wiil be great.

Comment: did you make sure to call it `appSettings` and `key`, and you should only need one configuration file for the project

Comment: see my Edit - rechecked

Comment: appSettingssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: Perfect! And maybe you can help - how can i store this key in config File?

Comment: you are storing the key `Volume` in the config file

Comment: means by pressing button - like `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting.Add("key", "value"); ` but it's require some permission for writing - hpw can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a separate config file, try this:

```
Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
config.AppSettings.File = "yourFileName"'tell Configuration what file to read
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified) ' save the Configuration setting
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings") ' update just the <appSettings> node
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the following technique, using `ConfigurationSection`. This allows you for painless manipulation of your configuration. But it is more specific upfront.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx